# Doubly Linked List Insertion With Recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm more or less just learning C, I was given an simple assignment that deals with doubly linked lists, dynamic data allocation, and recursion. I created an array of just 10 integers and I am trying to put these integers into a sorted doubly linked list using recursion. I am having some trouble with inserting nodes into the linked list; I think I have the first node down, but I'm not sure if the rest makes any sense. Right now I'm also getting a segmentation fault... Thank you for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

typedef struct node_ {
  int value;
  struct node_ *next;
  struct node_ *prev;
} node;

void insert(node **head, node *cur, node *p);
void print_list(node *cur);


void print_list(node *cur)
{
  if (!cur) {
    printf("\n");
    return;
  } else {
    printf("%d ", cur->value);
    print_list(cur->next);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int data[N] = {2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 4, 0, 8, 7, 100};
  node *p, *head;

  head = NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->value = data[i];
    insert(&head, head, p);
  }

  print_list(head);
}

void insert(node **head, node *cur, node *p)
{
  if(*head == NULL)
    {
      p->next = (*head);
//(*head)->prev = p;
      (*head) = p;
    }
  if(p->value < cur->value)
    {
      cur->prev->next = p;
      p->prev = cur->prev;
      cur->prev = p;
      p->next = cur;
    }
  insert(head, cur, p);

  //p->next = *head;
  //*head = p;
}
```

Comment: Side note: rather than `p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`, consider `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` as the cast is not needed and less chance of mis-sizing - less typing too.

Comment: what happens when you step through it in a debugger

Comment: When `if(*head == NULL)` it is unclear that `p->prev` is ever set.

Comment: using a sentry node will [simplify things](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Comment: Just a note about recursive functions, each recursive call is another call to the function along with all the function call setup and overhead. Recursive functions have their place, but don't simply replace an iterative function with a recursive function because you can. Consider reading a million elements into a list with a recursive function. That's is a whole lot of unnecessary function call and return overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your recursive `insert` function. It will be clear in the comments of my code:

```
void insert(node **head, node *cur, node *p)
{
  if(*head == NULL) // the list will contain a single element
  {
     p->next = p->prev = NULL;
    *head = p;
    return; // we're done for this case!
  }
  if(p->value < cur->value)
  {
    p->prev = cur->prev;
    p->next = cur;
    cur->prev = p;
    if(cur->prev != NULL) // what if cur is the head? there is no cur->prev!
      cur->prev->next = p;
    else
      *head = p; // p becomes the new head
    return; // we're done!
  }
  if(cur->next == NULL) // if cur is the last in the list, we just insert p after it
  {
    cur->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->prev = cur;
  }
  else // now we can proceed recursively and check the next element
    insert(head, cur->next, p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I tried to implement this code I received a segmentation fault. I ran a debugger and it said that there's an issue with the line if(p->value < cur->value). I'm not quite sure why that is.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried it and the output skipped many numbers and was only "2 7 9 100" for some reason.

Comment: Well, I guess you are in an advanced state now. You need to step through the debugger and see why the value 3 was not inserted and fix it :). My intention was not to do the whole assignment for you, but to give you a good push to fix the mistakes in the recursive function.

Comment: Turns out the issues is with the nested if statement. That if is never going to be true since I've already lost the value of cur->prev from the line above. So I did the assignment after the if. Thanks again!

Comment: ah yeah :D. Excellent!. Very glad to know that you took it to a good end. In a few time with some persistence, programming will never hurt you anymore ;) Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the function `insert` itself that has to allocate new node.

It should have two parameters: pointer to head and a value that to be added.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be writtem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node; 

void insert( node **current, int value )
{
    if ( *current == NULL || value < ( *current )->value )
    {
        node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        tmp->value = value;
        tmp->next = *current;

        if ( *current != NULL )
        {
            tmp->prev = ( *current )->prev;
            ( *current )->prev = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->prev = NULL;
        }

        *current = tmp;
    }
    else if ( ( *current )->next == NULL )
    {
        node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        tmp->value = value;
        tmp->next = ( *current )->next;
        tmp->prev = *current;
        ( *current )->next = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        insert( &( *current )->next, value );
    }
}

void print_list( node *current )
{
    if ( current == NULL )
    {
        printf( "\n" ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
        print_list( current->next );
    }
}    

#define N   10

int main( void )
{
    node *head = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        int value = rand() % N;
        printf( "%d ", value );
        insert( &head, value );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    print_list( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
4 9 0 0 6 7 2 7 3 3 
0 0 2 3 3 4 6 7 7 9
```

Of course you need to write also a recursive function that will free all allocated mempry for nodes.